# Pause all media playing in apps on macOS when incoming call

Tags: macos, sonoma

When I make a call or have an incoming call, apps like Youtube, Spotify, Chrome etc. do not pause or fade to background.

How can I set this on macOS Sonoma?

Comment: is the Pause key not working

Comment: @Ruskes yes it's work but on another my mac(2019) is lower sound of other media is playing. im curious about a Sonoma options :)